# Asp.net core web application API Post URL

Tags: azure, post, asp.net-core, deployment, swagger

I have a Asp.net core web application API with a post method which reads files from one storage account and write the processed file back into another storage. The post method works locally and is accessible via http://localhost:5000/api/values using postman. When I deploy the application as a Web App into the Azure App Service same URL format does not work on the azure.

For deployment I drag and drop my whole zipped application folder into https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeploy
(ref url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip)

I know the Asp.Net web application Azure Api App template has swagger config in them which make them accessible for other services after deployment. My question is considering I don't have any swagger config in my .net core application is this still possible to make the post method url accessible to consume it from Azure functions or logic app?